# LTSpice multiple input source noise analysis

Tags: ltspice, noise, transimpedance-amplifier

In my schematic, I have two input differential current source and I want to simulate the output noise of the system. However, the LTSpice noise simulation only allows me to put one input source in the simulation command. Is there any way to simulate noise with multiple input source?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why are you baffled with a "unique" input in the .noise analysis operator while being quite comfortable with the unique token "Output"? Read a manual, what the .noise command is for and how you use it. As for multiple noise sources: if you do the transient analysis, you can implement noise with behavioral sources and have as many noise sources as you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could modify your testbench to the following

[image]